# RAM issues on MacBook Pro mid-2014 on Yosemite

Tags: mac, memory, osx-yosemite

After a fresh reinstall of a MacBook Pro Retina mid-2014 bought in second-hand. I'm running some weird ram issues. Indeed, after one usage's week I realized I constantly use maximum of my ram. Now I'm 7.93GB over 8GB with just a Chrome browser open to write these down.

App memory is currently 5.56GB

Where should I look?

[image: EDITED Sreenshot]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of Activity Monitor's Memory view?

Comment: yep. It's done!

Comment: Memory **used** and memory **needed** are quite different. Every UNIX-based system (as is OSX) will aggressivly use RAM as a file cache instead of leaving it unused. This is a good thing.

Comment: Looks perfectly normal to me. Free memory is wasted memory. I suggest you read up on the Memory Pressure gauge [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107126/what-scale-or-measure-does-mavericks-and-yosemites-memory-pressure-adhere-to).

Comment: +1 for both above comments. Also note that swap used is zero, so it's at no point "run out of memory". It's managing it nicely. btw, Yosemite 'uses' memory much more aggressively than Mavericks, which has led a few people to ask why it's "all used up".